# Как запускать javac из cmd, чтобы правильно отображались кириллические символы в названии файла при выводе результатов компиляции?

Tags: java, кодировка, cmd, компиляция, кириллица

Компиляция java-файла с кириллицей в имени из командной строки. При выводе ошибок выводятся иероглифы. Как-то можно решить?

Comment: Какого файла? Компилируемого или что?

Comment: @LEQADA - "Компиляция java-файла с кириллицей в имени из командной строки. При выводе ошибок выводятся иероглифы...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В консоли (`cmd.exe`) перед вызовом компилятора переключите кодовую страницу командой

```
chcp 1251
```

Достаточно сделать это один раз при каждом запуске консоли. `javac` в русскоязычной Windows выводит сообщения в кодировке cp1251, а консоль использует cp866.

Пример:

```
E:\>chcp 1251
Текущая кодовая страница: 1251

E:\>javac -encoding utf8 ./Проверка.java ./Проверка2.java
.\Проверка2.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
                System.out.pri("Работает! 2");
                          ^
  symbol:   method pri(String)
  location: variable out of type PrintStream
1 error
```

Ключ `-encoding utf8` указывает на кодировку исходного файла.

Можно сделать наоборот, и объяснить `javac`, что он должен выводить текст в нужной кодировке, использовав ключ `-J-Dfile.encoding=cp866`:

```
E:\>chcp 866
Текущая кодовая страница: 866

E:\>javac -J-Dfile.encoding=cp866 -encoding utf8 ./Проверка.java ./Проверка2.java
.\Проверка2.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
                System.out.pri("Работает! 2");
                          ^
  symbol:   method pri(String)
  location: variable out of type PrintStream
1 error
```

Для вывода в utf-8 нужно включить кодовую страницу `65001` и задать кодировку `utf8` компилятору.

Чтобы установить кодировку вывода для всех вызовов java, можно использовать переменную окружения `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`.

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало! Ваш ответ на столько подробный и точный, что даже угадали название моего файла - Пример_1. Дело в том, что этот файл создали мои дети, а они только как месяц занимаются и про кодировки пока не очень понимают. А когда они узнали, что по-русски писать не желательно, то "обиделись" на программирование и на Java в частности. Пришлось обращаться за помощью.

Answer (score 2):

Как-то решить можно. Перевести все названия файлов в латиницу.

Ни одна книжка, ни одна справка или документация не рекомендует использовать в названиях классов и переменных кириллицу.

Comment: Может, сообщения об ошибках локализованы?

Comment: @VladD, вроде у ТС проблемы на этапе компиляции файла, в названии которого есть кириллические символы.

Comment: А, точно, я не дочитал вопрос.

Comment: Но всё же, мне кажется ваш ответ немного неправильным. «У меня проблема, когда я делаю X» — «Не делайте X вообще» . Это понятно, но вопрос ведь не об этом?

Comment: @VladD, нет, автор попросил решения. Я предложил хоть и очевидный, но workaround.

Comment: Т. е. джава неспособна по-человечески работать с юникодом? Да в таком случае её вообще куда подальше надо...

Comment: @Qwertiy, я не знаю, что это за проблема точно. В вопросе нет подробностей и примеров таких ошибок. Как выделил уважаемый zRrr, проблема воспроизводится не везде. У меня под Linux всё работает. Мой ответ - совет будущим пользователям, которые вдруг решат так делать.

Comment: @Qwertiy, проблема не в Java, а в Windows. На запрос Java о кодировке символов в ОС Windows отвечает "Win 1251", но консоль Windows живёт своей жизнью в кодировке DOS-866, Java про это ничего не знает и выводит сообщения в указанной ОС кодировке. В других ОС такой проблемы нет. Для корректного отображения сообщений в консоли Windows необходимо, как тут уже отмечено ранее, сменить кодировку консоли CHCP 1251. Либо конвертировать все строки выводимые приложением через native2ascii, но читать их потом в коде будет неудобно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, с консолью Windows по историческим причинам кириллические проблемы у многих языков. Java как раз-таки живет в юникоде.